# Find indexes of rows from an array that contains the rows of another array

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, python-3.9

Say I have two arrays `np1` and `np2` with different row sizes and column sizes. `np1` is known to contain all the elements of `np2`. Now I want to compare them row-wise, to know which rows of `np1` contains the rows of `np2`. More precisely, a row in `np1` may contain some elements of a row in `np2`. But what I need are the rows that contain all the elements of a certain row in `np2`. And for all the rows in `np2`, there is a row in `np1` that contains all its elements.

So the input will be `np1` with dimension `(n1,m1)`, `np2` with dimension `(n2,m2)` where  `n1>n2`, `m1=4`, and `m2=3`.

Output: an array with dimension `(n2*1)`. (Duplicates are possible, meaning a row in `np1` may contains 2 rows in `np2`.)

The data size that I am dealing with is rather big so I would like to have some efficient numpy or pandas solution.

For example:

```
A = [[1,2,4,3],[10,20,30,40],[100,200,28,16],[200,4,20,39]]

B = [[10,30,20],[200,28,16],[1,2,3]]
```

the result needs to be `[1,2,0]`.

I have already tried the np.isin and np.sort to reduce the size of np1 and then compare. But it gets complicated when I want to know their original indices.

For a duplicate example, a row in `np1` can contain two or more(in general two most) rows in `np2`. But for a row in `np2` is contained by one and only one row in `np1`.

Say now

```
A = [[1,2,4,3],[10,20,30,40],[100,200,28,16],[200,4,20,39]]

B = [[10,30,20],[200,28,16],[20,30,40],[1,2,3]]
```

the result is now `[1,2,1,0]`.

Comment: How big are your arrays? You could use broadcasting but this is expensive. Can you have duplicated values? How should this be handled?

Comment: In general the row size is ~1,000,000 , column size is 4 for np1 and 3 for np2. I can have duplicated values. i've tried np.isin and df.merge but didn't get what I want

Comment: Please provide an example with duplicated values, should all match?

Comment: Thank you, I put it above in the description

Comment: I believe by duplicated values request was meant an input like this: `source = [[1, 2, 2, 2], [1, 1, 1, 2]]; query = [[1, 1, 1]]` - could the result be `[0]` or `[1]` is the only valid solution?

Comment: You mean a boolean value? As long as the output can tell me the index number then no problem.

Comment: @noobn1 yes I meant if you have `A = [[1,2,3], [1,1,2], [2,2,3]]` and `B = [[1,1],[2,3],[4,5]]` what should be the output?

Comment: I didn't think about it the other way. Because for my arrays it doesn't have this problem. The rows in B will only be contained by one row in A.

Comment: @noobn1 so did the approach below work for you? You didn't answer about the duplicated numbers, can you have `A = [[1,2,3], [1,1,2], [2,2,3]]` and `B = [[1,1]]`?

Comment: @mozway sry i didn't notice i hadn't @ u. Your case is possible, the result will be simply [1]. In B there won't have an element [2,3] for my data. The approach below worked well, it took a little longer but it's ok. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a pure python solution, worst case is O(n²), best case is O(n):

```
from collections import Counter

cnt = list(map(Counter, A))

out = [next(i for i, a in enumerate(cnt) if b <= a)
       for b in list(map(Counter, B))]
```

Output: `[1, 2, 0]`

Comment: It shows '<=' not supported between instances of 'Counter' and 'Counter'. Did I do sth wrong?

Comment: which python version did you use? This is supported in python ≥3.10.

Comment: i am currently using 3.9. Ok I'll update it to 3.10 thx

Comment: Hi I tried your approach. For me it took 7-10 minutes for a np1 with the size of 100000*3 and a np2 with the size of 7000*3. I haven't tried it on a bigger model yet. Thanks a lot !

Comment: The issue is that you have to test many combinations. This will be tricky with numpy and would require to perform many comparisons in memory, which given your large sizes probably wouldn't fit in memory. I believe the `Counter` approach is a good compromise. One case in which numpy/pandas is likely less efficient.

Comment: yes i see your point here. I tried today with the original model, where np1 with size of ~7,000,000*4 and np2 of size ~1,000,000*3, now it gets expensive, took hours actually still not finished yet